# What is the main difference between using REST API instance App Server and normal HTTP WEB API server in Marklogic

Tags: api, rest, gradle, marklogic

With `mlNoRestServer=true` in gradle, we could disable creating REST api instance app server.
Basically, we could set up a WEB API without using the **recommended** REST API instance app server.

I want to seek what is the advantage of using the REST API instance app server.
My understanding is that once we use REST API instance app server, by default that app server will have [those features](https://docs.marklogic.com/guide/rest-dev/intro#id_82354). Am I right?

The feeling about **recommended** REST API instance approach is that all ML training demo projects using REST API instance app server. With REST API instance, one could extend its service via either REST API service approach or DS approach.

However, my current understanding is that we could implement exactly the same features with a normal HTTP server in ML without using REST API instance app server.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The REST API is an extensible REST application. It does alot for you. However, it comes at the cost of some layers of evaluation that you may not need.  Nothing stops you from creating main modules on your own and doing direct execution.

In terms of "By Default, your application will have those features".  Features available on port 8000, 8001, 8002 vary based on rewriters.  The list you have is based on using the REST API itself to create a new REST instance and give a default set of endpoints. ML-Gradle is a separate project. Although it currently does appear to match the information on the docs since it uses the v1 rest-apis endpoint, that could always change.

Your approach may benefit from MarkLogic Data Services rather then extending the REST API. It is a lightweight config file pointing to your code. Here is the [link to a page about Data Services Declarations including OpenAPI](https://docs.marklogic.com/guide/rest-dev/OpenAPI). I listed this because from that page, you can see additional links to Java and Node.js

Comment: Could you please explain more about the benefit of using REST API and what is the cost?

Comment: The benefit is you get a bunch of OOTB endpoints for common and useful functionality - e.g. /v1/documents and /v1/search. Note too that a REST API server is an app server, it just uses a special rewriter to enable that useful functionality. However, for custom endpoints, you may find Data Services to be a better fit because of the ability to generate client code for invoking for endpoints. Data Services also do not have any framework/rewriter associated with them, which in practice usually makes them easier to implement.